# easy way to unzip file

Tags: go, zip, unzip

Is there a easy way to unzip file with Go?

right now my code is:

```
func Unzip(src, dest string) error {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Close()

    for _, f := range r.File {
        rc, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer rc.Close()

        path := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)
        if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            os.MkdirAll(path, f.Mode())
        } else {
            f, err := os.OpenFile(
                path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            defer f.Close()

            _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Comment: There is a problem with your code above - you are deferring the close of all the files in the `for` loop until `Extract` exits.  This will work fine for small numbers of files but if you had 1000s in the zip then you'll run out of file descriptors. Factor the contents of the `for` loop to a function or closure to fix.

Comment: I believe you also need `os.MkdirAll(dest, 0755)` right before your for loop.

Answer (score 70, accepted):

Slight rework of the OP's solution to create the containing directory `dest` if it doesn't exist, and to wrap the file extraction/writing in a closure to eliminate stacking of `defer .Close()` calls per [@Nick Craig-Wood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/164234/nick-craig-wood)'s comment:

```
func Unzip(src, dest string) error {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := r.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    os.MkdirAll(dest, 0755)

    // Closure to address file descriptors issue with all the deferred .Close() methods
    extractAndWriteFile := func(f *zip.File) error {
        rc, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer func() {
            if err := rc.Close(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()

        path := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)

        // Check for ZipSlip (Directory traversal)
        if !strings.HasPrefix(path, filepath.Clean(dest) + string(os.PathSeparator)) {
            return fmt.Errorf("illegal file path: %s", path)
        }

        if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            os.MkdirAll(path, f.Mode())
        } else {
            os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(path), f.Mode())
            f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            defer func() {
                if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }()

            _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    for _, f := range r.File {
        err := extractAndWriteFile(f)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

**Note:** Updated to include Close() error handling as well (if we're looking for best practices, may as well follow ALL of them).

Comment: Best answer. I really appreciate the closure. I have had an issue unzipping archives that have too many files. This solves that.

Comment: This example would not work with zip files that had nested directories, since the output directory was never created. The code assumed that the directory had a separate entry, for example `some/dir/` which could then be created, and after that `some/dir/file.txt` could be extracted in that. But the files are just listed alone with their full path (no separate directory entry). Which resulted in it failing because the directory was not created before trying to create the file in it. I edited the answer to fix this.

Comment: @Astockwell what is the use of  `if f.FileInfo().IsDir() { ` is it to check whether the file is a directory and if yes create it parent directories? if so why can't we use the code in else `os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(path), f.Mode())` part alone for making parent directories?

Comment: if the zip file is not trusted, it may cause a directory traversal vuln. see https://gist.github.com/virusdefender/f8c127ab420942dd99acbf269aca9cc7

Comment: The directory created with os.MkdirAll is using the perms of the file, so it probably it will be created with 644, failing to write the file

Comment: @adrianlzt filepath.Dir(...) will only create the parent directory. If the ZIP-File contains an empty directory the IF is needed to create this directory and not only its parent.

Comment: @Falco check this example of what I am saying https://gist.github.com/adrianlzt/985cc5a90f23748a685f4873d9ab0978

Comment: @adrianlzt you are right, but fixing this does not seem trivial - if the folder should be read protected after unpacking, one would have to change permissions while extracting and change them back afterwards.

Comment: yes, maybe the best option is check how it is implemented in "unzip" binary

Answer (score 6):

I'm using `archive/zip` package to read .zip files and copy to the local disk. Below is the source code to unzip .zip files for my own needs.

```
import (
    "archive/zip"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

func unzip(src, dest string) error {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer r.Close()

    for _, f := range r.File {
        rc, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer rc.Close()

        fpath := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)
        if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            os.MkdirAll(fpath, f.Mode())
        } else {
            var fdir string
            if lastIndex := strings.LastIndex(fpath,string(os.PathSeparator)); lastIndex > -1 {
                fdir = fpath[:lastIndex]
            }

            err = os.MkdirAll(fdir, f.Mode())
            if err != nil {
                log.Fatal(err)
                return err
            }
            f, err := os.OpenFile(
                fpath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            defer f.Close()

            _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
    }
    return nil
}
```

Comment: I was trying to use your code but it seems to have an error in the line `if lastIndex := strings.LastIndex(fpath,string(os.PathSeparator)); lastIndex > -1 {`. Where does `strings` come from?

Comment: Sorry, I left out the strings package.

Comment: `strings.LastIndex(fpath,string(os.PathSeparator))` can replaced with `filepath.Dir(fpath)`

Comment: As virusdefender said in a comment to Astockwell s answer (which is now fixed), this answer here is still vulnerable to directory traversal for untrusted archives: https://gist.github.com/virusdefender/f8c127ab420942dd99acbf269aca9cc7

Answer (score 4):

Most answers here are wrong, as they assume that the Zip archive will emit
directory entries. Zip archives are [not required to emit directory
entries](//stackoverflow.com/questions/65617164), and so given an archive such as that, a naive program will crash
upon encountering the first non-root file, as no directories will ever be
created, and the file creation will fail as the directory has not been created
yet. Here is a different approach:

```
package main

import (
   "archive/zip"
   "os"
   "path"
)

func unzip(source, dest string) error {
   read, err := zip.OpenReader(source)
   if err != nil { return err }
   defer read.Close()
   for _, file := range read.File {
      if file.Mode().IsDir() { continue }
      open, err := file.Open()
      if err != nil { return err }
      name := path.Join(dest, file.Name)
      os.MkdirAll(path.Dir(name), os.ModeDir)
      create, err := os.Create(name)
      if err != nil { return err }
      defer create.Close()
      create.ReadFrom(open)
   }
   return nil
}

func main() {
   unzip("Microsoft.VisualCpp.Tools.HostX64.TargetX64.vsix", "tools")
}
```

Comment: This is now integrated in the answer from Astockwell. But don't you, in your answer, also need to create directories which don't have files in them?

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer using 7zip with Go, which would give you something like this.

```
func extractZip() {
    fmt.Println("extracting", zip_path)
    commandString := fmt.Sprintf(`7za e %s %s`, zip_path, dest_path)
    commandSlice := strings.Fields(commandString)
    fmt.Println(commandString)
    c := exec.Command(commandSlice[0], commandSlice[1:]...)
    e := c.Run()
    checkError(e)
}
```

Better [example code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20330210/golang-1-2-unzip-password-protected-zip-file)

However, if using 7zip isn't possible, then try this. Defer a recover to catch the panics. ([Example](https://github.com/Unknwon/build-web-application-with-golang_EN/blob/master/code/src/apps/ch.2.3/panic_and_recover/main.go))

```
func checkError(e error){
  if e != nil {
    panic(e)
  }
}
func cloneZipItem(f *zip.File, dest string){
    // Create full directory path
    path := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)
    fmt.Println("Creating", path)
    err := os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(path), os.ModeDir|os.ModePerm)
    checkError(err)

    // Clone if item is a file
    rc, err := f.Open()
    checkError(err)
    if !f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
        // Use os.Create() since Zip don't store file permissions.
        fileCopy, err := os.Create(path)
        checkError(err)
        _, err = io.Copy(fileCopy, rc)
        fileCopy.Close()
        checkError(err)
    }
    rc.Close()
}
func Extract(zip_path, dest string) {
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(zip_path)
    checkError(err)
    defer r.Close()
    for _, f := range r.File {
        cloneZipItem(f, dest)
    }
}
```

Comment: As virusdefender said in a comment to Astockwell s answer (which is now fixed), this answer here is still vulnerable to directory traversal for untrusted archives: gist.github.com/virusdefender/f8c127ab420942dd99acbf269aca9cc7

Answer (score 2):

I have been doing some browsing of google and repeatedly found people saying that there is no library that can handle that. Maybe I missed a custom repository in my search though and someone else will find it for us.

You may be able to make use of `io.Copy(src, dest)` to ease the process but I haven't tested it at all.

For instance:

```
os.MkDirAll(dest, r.File.Mode)
d, _ := os.Open(dest)
io.Copy(r.File, d)
```

Honestly to me your code looks pretty nice and if I were to do an Extract function myself (and the above doesn't work) then I would probably take a page from your book.

Answer (score 2):

While working on the query for catching ZipSlip vulnerabilities in Go on [LGTM.com](https://lgtm.com) (of which I am a developer), I noticed code similar to the accepted answer in several projects, e.g. [rclone](https://lgtm.com/projects/g/rclone/rclone/snapshot/9031f26a752a2a3d9203c28e32442dcb57b12982/files/cmd/rcd/rcd.go?sort=name&dir=ASC&mode=heatmap#x94b94cc207565e13:1).

As @woogoo has pointed out, this code is vulnerable to ZipSlip, so I believe the answer should be updated to something like the following (code taken from [rclone fix](https://github.com/rclone/rclone/commit/32d5af8fb61adf1f3ebdadaf2c61350587965b0f)):

```
func Unzip(src, dest string) error {
    dest = filepath.Clean(dest) + string(os.PathSeparator)

    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err := r.Close(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }()

    os.MkdirAll(dest, 0755)

    // Closure to address file descriptors issue with all the deferred .Close() methods
    extractAndWriteFile := func(f *zip.File) error {
        path := filepath.Join(dest, f.Name)
        // Check for ZipSlip: https://snyk.io/research/zip-slip-vulnerability
        if !strings.HasPrefix(path, dest) {
            return fmt.Errorf("%s: illegal file path", path)
        }

        rc, err := f.Open()
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        defer func() {
            if err := rc.Close(); err != nil {
                panic(err)
            }
        }()

        if f.FileInfo().IsDir() {
            os.MkdirAll(path, f.Mode())
        } else {
            os.MkdirAll(filepath.Dir(path), f.Mode())
            f, err := os.OpenFile(path, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, f.Mode())
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
            defer func() {
                if err := f.Close(); err != nil {
                    panic(err)
                }
            }()

            _, err = io.Copy(f, rc)
            if err != nil {
                return err
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    for _, f := range r.File {
        err := extractAndWriteFile(f)
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }

    return nil
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
package main

import (
    "os"
    "io"
    "io/ioutil"
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "archive/zip"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    if err := foo("test.zip"); err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
    }
}

func foo(yourZipFile string) error {
    tmpDir, err := ioutil.TempDir("/tmp", "yourPrefix-")
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer os.RemoveAll(tmpDir)
    if filenames, err := Unzip(yourZipFile, tmpDir); err != nil {
        return err
    } else {
        for f := range filenames {
            fmt.Println(filenames[f])
        }
    }
    return nil
}


func Unzip(src string, dst string) ([]string, error) {
    var filenames []string
    r, err := zip.OpenReader(src)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer r.Close()
    for f := range r.File {
        dstpath := filepath.Join(dst, r.File[f].Name)
        if !strings.HasPrefix(dstpath, filepath.Clean(dst) + string(os.PathSeparator)) {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("%s: illegal file path", src)
        }
        if r.File[f].FileInfo().IsDir() {
            if err := os.MkdirAll(dstpath, os.ModePerm); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            }
        } else {
            if rc, err := r.File[f].Open(); err != nil {
                return nil, err
            } else {
                defer rc.Close()
                if of, err := os.OpenFile(dstpath, os.O_WRONLY|os.O_CREATE|os.O_TRUNC, r.File[f].Mode()); err != nil {
                    return nil, err
                } else {
                    defer of.Close()
                    if _, err = io.Copy(of, rc); err != nil {
                        return nil, err
                    } else {
                        of.Close()
                        rc.Close()
                        filenames = append(filenames, dstpath)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    if len(filenames) == 0 {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("zip file is empty")
    }
    return filenames, nil
}
```

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Because this question already has a well established answer, it would help to add an explanation of what advantages your answer has.