# Golang unzip retain the original file timestamp

Tags: go

I am using approach described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20357223/easy-way-to-unzip-file-with-golang) to unzip a zip file into destination directory.

The problem I am having is, the files in destination folder (which are results of unzip) having the unzipped timestamp instead of the original "zipped" version file timestamp.

Any idea how can I retain the original timestamp?

Based on my research it seems, I might need to use something like os.Chtimes(...) function to reset the timestamp after file copy, which seems little bit cumbersome. Any suggestions?

Comment: Either you call [`os.Chtimes`](https://pkg.go.dev/os#Chtimes) or you find a package that does it for you. Either way there's no way to create files with a certain timestamps without setting those timestamps.

Comment: @CeriseLimón Thanks. I got the date part working fine by using chtimes and modtime, but the "time" part is not correct. Seems UTC to EST messing up. Need to find out a way to get those corrected.

Comment: Use [Modified](https://godoc.org/archive/zip#FileHeader.Modified) instead of [ModTime](https://godoc.org/archive/zip#FileHeader.ModTime).

Comment: @iLoveReflection I am using Modified, see the documentation describing ModTime is deprecated. Thanks!